# Reading CSV file into Node.js then INSERT into SQLite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, csv

So i have attempted many diffrent things, diffrent modules such as fast-csv and several diffrent similar stackoverflow solutions with no success
and my main goal is to have a CSV-file that i want to get into SQLite via Node.js

My current Success is that iv managed to get the CSV-file into the console.
But no matter the size of the CSV-file i keep getting:
Error : SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range.

At first i attempted to have a file with :

```
ID, Name, Phone, LastName, Adress
1 , Alex, 010-5555, Alexsson, Southstreet 1
2 , Axel, 050-1111, Axelsson, Northstreet 2
```

then filling with data bellow that in an excel page later saved as a CSV file.

Then for the sake of testing i had a file with :

```
ID
1
```

but no matter what i ended up with the same error.
Here is my code.
Is it just a typo or is what im trying to do actually not possible in the way i am attempting it?

```
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var http = require("http");

http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    var html = buildHtml(req);

    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "text/html",
      "Content-Length": html.length,
      Expires: new Date().toUTCString(),
    });
    res.end(html);
  })
  .listen(8080);
// open database in memory
let db = new sqlite3.Database("test.db", (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log("Connected to the in-memory SQlite database.");
});

const csvParser = require("csv-parser");
const fs = require("fs");
const filepath = "./sampleData.csv";

fs.createReadStream(filepath)
  .on("error", () => {
    // handle error
  })

  .pipe(csvParser())
  .on("data", (row) => {
    console.log(row);
    // use row data

    let sql = `INSERT INTO testtable(ID, Name, Phone, LastName, Adress) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;
    db.run(sql, row, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log(row);
    });

    // close the database connection
    db.close((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
      console.log("Close the database connection.");
    });
  })

  .on("end", () => {
    // handle end of CSV
  });
```

Comment: can you please pass phone column value as `123` static and see?

Comment: The phone column is set to text :) but for the sake of testing i did what you asked and ended up with the same error msg! thx for the comment tho!

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough changing the "ID, Name, Phone, LastName, Adress"
in the CSV-file to
`1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 5` 
and pushes the data into the SQlite database with an
"SQLITE_MISUSE: Database handle is closed"
per data object but it still goes into the database!

any idea why ? it kinda works right now even if i feel like something is like it shouldnt be.